# VS 2019 в режиме отладки закрывает окно

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

Windows 10 x64. Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise.
Создаю новый проект по шаблону C# Windows Forms App (.NET Framework).
Ничего не меняя, сразу запускаю в режиме отладки.
Окно основной формы открывается и тут же закрывается.
В режиме без отладки все нормально - окно открывается и остается открытым, пока его не закроешь.
В чем может быть причина?
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Такого быть не должно. Вы код или настройки точно не меняли? Попробуйте создать второй проект или запустить окно из консольного проекта

Comment: Точно не наоборот?

Comment: Точно не наоборот. При запуске из консольного приложения то же самое. Диагностика одна: The program '[6460] MyForm.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

Comment: Винда какая стоит? Антивирь? Система давно установлена? [Если вин 10] - Обновления какие?

Comment: Очень похоже на баг в VS, Я бы советовал попробовать или проверить обновления на VS или поставить VS 2017.

Comment: OC Win10 Pro x64, установлена пару месяцев назад. Антивирус Comodo Internet Security Premium. Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise 16.4.3. Разумеется, до того, как писать сюда, отключал антивирус. Не помогло :(

Comment: Варианта только 4: Винда, Comodo, вирус, VS. Еще возможно не хватает каких-то библиотек или "избыточные", конфликтуют. В системном журнале, в управлении компьютером ошибка появляется? Там библиотека будет указана или другая инфа... 'Access violation' должно быть там. Если библиотека от комодо преступник найден

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**РЕШЕНО.**
Большое спасибо всем откликнувшимся, особенно [cProject](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/306187/cproject).

*Поиск решения:*
В журналах событий Журналы Windows/Приложения в записях об ошибке
`Имя сбойного приложения: MyForm.exe
Имя сбойного модуля: clr.dll
Путь сбойного модуля: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll`
Dll-ка на поверку нормальная. Что же ей не нравиться?

В журналах событий Журналы Windows/Система в записях об ошибке
`Параметры разрешений для конкретного приложения не дают разрешения для приложения, выполняемого в контейнере.`
Политики безопасности менять пока не хочется, но настораживает тот факт, что система пытается поместить отлаживаемое приложение в контейнер (как небезопасное), а это фишка Comodo. Почему же это происходит даже при выключенном антивирусе?

Иду в VS. В свойствах проекта (закладка Debug) ставлю галочку Enable native code debugging и снова запускаю отладку (антивирус выключен). Получаю сообщение отладчика, что Access violation вызывает cmdvrt32.dll. Это библиотека Comodo. В списке запущенных процессов вижу, что несмотря на то, что антивирус не только выключен, но сделан выход из программы, все равно есть 
процессы от Comodo. Все-таки антивирус!

*Решение:*
Первое, что напрашивается, - снести Comodo и поставить другой антивирус. Но я решил поступить иначе. В Comodo/Расширенные настройки/Containment/Авто-Containment добавил правило игнорировать Visual Studio. Ошибка исчезла.
Profit!